# Using Ruby, how can I confirm that an XML snippit is valid?

Tags: ruby, xml, xmpp, xmpp4r

As some of you make know, I'm [working on XMPP (Jabber) integration for the StackOverflow chat system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57316/63420#63420), as an XMPP component written in Ruby using [the xmpp4r package](http://home.gna.org/xmpp4r/).

I'm struggling with one issue (well, many issues, but *one issue at the moment* :-) I am taking the JSON feed from the chat and extracting the HTML for the messages. I am using [The Ruby TidyHTML bindings](http://tidy.rubyforge.org/) to convert the HTML from the JSON fed to XHTML, so that I can send it as an XMPP message -- since XMPP messages are just XML, converting the HTML to XHTMl should make it valid XML which I can just stick into the `<message>` stanza.

For [most messages](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/263510#263510), it works great!

[image: My Mind Is Blown]

However for other messages, it completely chokes -- the XMPP server closes the stream and the script grinds to a halt. (And rchern and others in The Tavern get upset. Well, maybe not *upset*, but they laugh at me. This makes me sad!)

I am almost certain that what's happing is, for some reason or other, the messages are not valid XML, and so the XMPP server is closing the connection because it encounters a parse error in the XML stream from the Ruby component. Here's an example of one such message:

```
<message to='jeswah@smart-safe-secure.com/Token' type='groupchat' xmlns='jabber:client'><body>&lt;div class=&quot;onebox ob-message&quot;&gt;&lt;a class=&quot;roomname&quot; href=&quot;/transcript/message/263372#263372&quot;&gt;&lt;span title=&quot;2010-11-04 19:20:23Z&quot;&gt;1 hour ago&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;, by &lt;span class=&quot;user-name&quot;&gt;Fosco&lt;/span&gt; &lt;br/&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;quote&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;room-mini&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;room-mini-header&quot;&gt;&lt;h3&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;small-site-logo&quot; title=&quot;Gaming&quot; alt=&quot;Gaming&quot; width=&quot;16&quot; height=&quot;16&quot; src=&quot;http://sstatic.net/gaming/img/favicon.ico&quot; /&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;span class=&quot;room-name&quot;&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28/minecraft-talk&quot;&gt;Minecraft Talk&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/h3&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;room-mini-description&quot;&gt;Everything Minecraft, including classic and survival mode&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;room-current-user-count&quot; title=&quot;current users&quot;&gt;9&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspark&quot; style=&quot;height:25px;width:205px&quot;&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:13px;left:0px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:9px;left:8px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:2px;left:16px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:8px;left:24px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:1px;left:32px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:1px;left:56px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:0px;left:64px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:0px;left:88px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:0px;left:96px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:11px;left:104px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:7px;left:112px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:7px;left:120px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:25px;left:128px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:14px;left:136px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:4px;left:144px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:7px;left:152px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:19px;left:160px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:19px;left:168px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:12px;left:176px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar&quot; style=&quot;width:8px;height:11px;left:184px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;mspbar now&quot; style=&quot;height:25px;left:154px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;clear-both&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</body><html xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im'><body xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><div class="onebox ob-message"><a class="roomname" href="/transcript/message/263372#263372"><span title="2010-11-04 19:20:23Z">1 hour ago</span></a>, by <span class="user-name">Fosco</span><br />
<div class="quote">
<div class="room-mini"><div class="room-mini-header">
<h3><img class="small-site-logo" title="Gaming" alt="Gaming" width="16" height="16" src="http://sstatic.net/gaming/img/favicon.ico" />&nbsp;<span class="room-name"><a href="http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28/minecraft-talk">Minecraft Talk</a></span></h3>
<div class="room-mini-description">Everything Minecraft, including classic and survival mode</div>
</div>
<div class="room-current-user-count" title="current users">9</div>
<div class="mspark" style="height:25px;width:205px">
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:13px;left:0px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:9px;left:8px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:2px;left:16px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:8px;left:24px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:1px;left:32px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:1px;left:56px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:0px;left:64px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:0px;left:88px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:0px;left:96px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:11px;left:104px;"></div><div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:7px;left:112px;"></div><div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:7px;left:120px;"></div><div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:25px;left:128px;"></div><div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:14px;left:136px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:4px;left:144px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:7px;left:152px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:19px;left:160px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:19px;left:168px;"></div><div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:12px;left:176px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar" style="width:8px;height:11px;left:184px;"></div>
<div class="mspbar now" style="height:25px;left:154px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear-both"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body></html></message>
```

(This message happened to be a quote of a oneboxed link to a chat room)

Here was the error Ruby gave me:

```
IOError: stream closed
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmpp4r/stream.rb:594:in `empty?'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:153:in `empty?'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rexml/parsers/baseparser.rb:193:in `pull'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rexml/parsers/sax2parser.rb:92:in `parse'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmpp4r/streamparser.rb:79:in `parse'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmpp4r/stream.rb:75:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmpp4r/stream.rb:72:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmpp4r/stream.rb:72:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmpp4r/stream.rb:72:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmpp4r/connection.rb:119:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmpp4r/component.rb:70:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmpp4r/connection.rb:77:in `connect'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmpp4r/component.rb:47:in `connect'
./classes/SOXMPP_Bridge.rb:20:in `initialize'
./soxmpp.rb:81:in `new'
./soxmpp.rb:81
```

#### Finally, my question!

Given that sending invalid XML to the XMPP server kicks me off, is there any way using Ruby I can validate (and, preferably, *correct*) the XML before sending it to the XMPP server? Most likely, *correcting* it will be a matter of my writing additional code for each case where Tidy isn't producing valid XML, but I'd at least like to stop the script from crashing. So, how can I validate the XML before sending it to the XMPP server?

Comment: Thanks to Michael Mrozek for the screenshot material!

Comment: @TreyE: I'm not sure specifically what you're asking... There isn't a test at the moment. The code just happily takes every HTML message from the chat and parses it to XHTML, and sends that to the XMPP server. I can post relevant code if that helps.

Comment: Full source is available [in trac](http://trac.digitalfruition.com/soxmpp/browser/trunk) or [in subversion](https://svn.smart-safe-secure.com/soxmpp/trunk)

Comment: I don't know how to create ejabber client by ruby code, plz help me if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual error in this case is your `&nbsp;`.  According to [XEP-0071](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0071.html#bizrules), section 8, point 5:

> Section 11.1 of XMPP Core stipulates that character entities other than the five general entities defined in Section 4.6 of the XML specification (i.e., &lt;, &gt;, &amp;, &apos;, and &quot;) MUST NOT be sent over an XML stream. Therefore implementations of XHTML-IM MUST NOT include predefined XHTML 1.0 entities such as &nbsp; -- instead, implementations MUST use the equivalent character references as specified in Section 4.1 of the XML specification (even in non-obvious places such as URIs that are included in the 'href' attribute).

So this issue is about more than just generating well-formed XML, which is a pre-requisite.  You'll also want to ensure that you're only using XHTML from the approved set in [section 6](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0071.html#def).

In short, you need to read XEP-0071.

Comment: `@html_body.gsub!(/&nbsp;/,' ')` seems to have made the specific message that was crashing XMPP before stop crashing it now, which is great! However that's clearly just one entity -- I'll need a more robust solution to be sure the XMPP component stays active. Thanks a lot! I'll credit you in the changelog :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe actually converting to XML with [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) will help? You can then re-serialize for the XMPP stream.
Also, if you want your stuff to scale a bit and avoid memory bloats, switch to [Blather](https://github.com/sprsquish/blather) instead of XMPP4r. Also the DSL is pretty awesome!

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out Nokogiri! Can Blather create an [XMPP component](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0114.html)? That is to say, right now the script creates a new subdomain of my XMPP server, and creates multiple MUC rooms on that subdomain. It's not just a way to connect to an XMPP server using an existing JID...

Comment: Ho, yes, specifically if you want to use a component, I would recommand Blather or even Skates. XMPP4R will probably break pretty quickly as traffic increases.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running on *nix?  If so, I'd delegate the problem to `xmllint`, a program that is a part of [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/).  I work with a system that generates xml before sending it over the net; we validate our xml with xmllint, like so:

```
    command = "xmllint #{temp_file_path} --schema #{schema_file_path} --noout 2>&1"
    output = `#{command}`
    if $? != 0
      temp_dir.keep
      $stderr.puts "Error validating xml: running command #{command.inspect}"
      $stderr.puts output
      exit(1)
    end
```

You'll need to adapt this to your situation, of course, but the basic idea works well.  If you don't have a DTD, leave out the "--schema" bit.

Comment: I am running on Linux but I'd prefer the system be OS independent as I know the community has many Windows only users. Also, firing up an external command for every chat message will *be awful* for performance... have you been in chat recently? ;-)

Comment: Unless there's a rubygem for that...? Don't get me wrong, it's a good idea, but...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Tidy.  Use the [HTML5 parser](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/downloads/detail?name=html5-0.10.0.gem), then dump the DOM it generates to XML.  If you can produce a DOM, you can produce well-formed XML from it every time.  It will also have the advantage of producing roughly the same DOM that most modern browsers will give you.

Comment: This sounds *extremely* promising and I look forward to trying it!

Comment: That said, Joe is correct, and additionally, html5lib won't fix the issue he pointed out.