# Schema for send image in xmpp

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xmpp

i would like to know which is the xmpp schema for send images or data.
And I would like to know if is possible send an image from your iphone inside a xmpp message and how ??
Thanks !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198562/how-can-i-send-an-image-on-the-web-in-an-xmpp-jabber-message

Comment: Do you want to send an image embedded in a chat message?  If yes, then it's a dupe of the question @Flow linked.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/legastero/4497613